# useEffect executing despite no change in dependency

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-effect

I have read several similar questions and tried the solutions in each but none seem to be working and do not match my use case exactly as I am using react-router.

In my App.js I set the value of a refreshTokenId to some UUID. I have a child component in App.js, that on initial render sends an API call to fetch some data. Now I have added refreshTokenId as the dependency to my useEffect hook, inwhich the API call is contained. I am using react-router and when I navigate from the page and then back, the API call is fired again despite the fact that the dependcy (i.e. refreshTokenId) has not changed. I confirmed this by travelling through time in my Redux dev tools and observing the state. The  first, and only time the refreshTokenId changes, is when my App.js is mounted. This is because I initially set the value of the refreshTokenId in a useEffect in App.js.

I do not understand why the useEffect in my sub-component is firing when the dependencies are not changing. 
I have put some code below to demonstrate the issue:

```
childComponent:
const DataManager = (props) => {

    const refreshTokenId = props.refreshTokenId
    useEffect(() =>{
        props.datasetInfoRequest() 
    }, [refreshTokenId]); <---refreshTokenId does not change when routing around

const mapDispatchToProps =  dispatch => {
    return {
        datasetInfoRequest: () => dispatch(actions.datasetInfoInit())
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        refreshTokenId: state.refresh.refreshTokenId,
        lastRefreshed: state.refresh.lastRefreshed
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DataManager);
```

```
App.js
const App = (props)=> {
    useEffect(()=>{
        props.refresh();
    },[]);

return (
    <div className="App">
            <Switch>
                <Route path = "/manager" component = {DataManager} />
                <Route path = "/index" component = {HomePage} />
                <Route path = "/logout" component = {Logout} />
            </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return{
        refresh: () => dispatch(actions.appRefresh()) 
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: may be the component gets remounted because parent remounted

Comment: App.js wouldn't get remounted though. I was thinking perhaps react-router is causing it to re-render despite the old state. But not sure how to avoid that, otherwise my app makes additional API calls which destroy D3 graphs I have

Comment: you can use React devtools `Profile` feature and then see what caused it to re-render or remount

Comment: is the refresh state a new object? using something like `createSelector` from the `reselect` library to memoize your values.

Comment: The refresh action itself is only dispatched once, when the App.js loads. The refreshTokenId is set then and then also  set when a user selects refresh, in which case I actually do want to dispatch additional API calls. But not unless the refresh button is hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `render` instead of `component`:

```
<Route path="/manager" render={DataManager} />
```

When you use **component**, the router creates a new component on every render.

When you use **render**, the router will just re-render the component.

If you need to, i.e. for class components, you can pass a function that returns JSX:

```
<Route
  path="/manager"
  render={(props) => <DataManager {...props} />}
/>
```

Comment: From the react-router docs: "When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the component prop, you would create a new component every render". I have not porvided an inline function, so is this really the case? Or am I misunderstanding the docs...

Comment: Hi @TeeJ - your component *is* a function